# How to use wildcards in nant xmlpoke file path

Tags: nant, xmlpoke

I am using the xmlpoke task in nant and am looking for a way to use a wildcard when addressing the xml file. Right now I have a file path like project\appFiles\project{versionNumber}\fileToUpdate.xml, I would like to use a wildcard so its something like project\appFiles\project*\fileToUpdate.xml so I don't have to update the version number every time.

How do you get it to respect wildcards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking all over the web, it doesn't look like this is possible, and by design. Like copy command (todir), the file path must point to a single file so no wildcards allowed (Found info on copy command, assuming same applies for XMLPoke, but could confirm exactly).

I ended up changing some design stuff so now the version number is easily calculated by the program calling the script, so passing in not an issue anymore.